# Autocompletebox in wp7.5 toolkit shows wrongly

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, autocompletebox

I am using autocompletebox toolkit from windowsphone7.5 version. It works well in wp7.1 toolkit.

If I use autocompletion with inner control margin it's not worked properly, it shows the result on the top,

Here I attached the autocompletion error screenshot.

[image]

This is the code :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="76" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="400" ValueMemberBinding="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="acBox" Margin="10,0,10,0" ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryListitems}">
    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
  </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Can you place any value in FilterMode?